# How can one explain gravitational time dilation in non-rotating bodies?

Tags: general-relativity, time-dilation

A clock on the surface of the Earth (assuming it does not rotate) will accumulate around 0.0219 seconds less than a distant observer over a period of one year (assuming the observer is using Schwarzschild coordinates).

In comparison, a clock on the surface of the sun will accumulate around 66.4 seconds less in a year.

How is this possible and what causes this phenomenon.

Reference: Wikipedia

The formula for calculating the time dilation caused by a non-rotating mass is

$$ t_o = t_f \sqrt{1 - \frac{2GM}{c^2r}} = t_f \sqrt{1 - \frac{r_s}{r}} $$

where:

$t_0$ is the proper time between events A and B for a slow-ticking observer within the gravitational field

$t_f$ is the coordinate time between events A and B for a fast-ticking observer at an arbitrarily large distance from the massive object

$G$ is the gravitational constant

$M$ is the mass of the object creating the gravitational field

$r$ is the radial coordinate of the observer (which is analogous to the classical distance 
from the center of the object, but is actually a Schwarzschild coordinate),

$c$ is the speed of light

Comment: You seem to just be copying wikipedia. What are you confused about?

Comment: Are you asking how your equation is derived, or are you asking what the physicial origin of the time dilation is?

Comment: Your 0.0219 seconds per year is off by a good deal. It's about 0.49 seconds per year. You missed two effects that are much larger effects than the Earth's gravitation. We're orbiting the Sun at 30 km/s at about 1 AU from the Sun. The special and general relativistic effects from this orbit are responsible for the bulk of the time dilation. The Earth's gravitational field, not so much.

Comment: This is your second "Why?" type question in rather short order. That's not the best approach to learning physics.

Comment: Yes John I am mostly wondering about the physical origin of gravitational time-dilation. I have come across the reply that 'Why' is outside the domain of physics but I was wondering if there are any speculative theories or thought experiments or explanation of probable theories (not yet accepted by Science faculty).

Comment: (I started to compose an answer, but the question was closed.) I think what you are looking for is the _Newtonian approximation of General Relativity_. Its core idea is that the main observable effect of GR gravitation in the weak fields is the time dilation $t_o=t_f\sqrt{1+2\phi/c^2}$ where $\phi$ is the Newtonian gravitational potential. After one postulates such dilation, the theory works the other way round: it is this dilation that causes and explains all usual gravitational phenomena you are familiar with. For example, free bodies fall, fixed bodies exert forces on their support, ...

Comment: ... and waves go along curves deviated from straight lines (that applies to all kinds of waves, be they light waves or de Broglie waves of quantum particles).

Comment: @VanitaAshar: I wish I could post this as an answer, but anyway: You don't actually need general relativity to understand this effect. In a uniformly accelerating rocket ship in _special_ relativity, clocks higher up in the apparent gravitational field will tick faster than clocks lower down. The [Pound-Rebka experiment](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pound%E2%80%93Rebka_experiment) will yield a non-null result. (cont'd)

Comment: (cont'd) This happens because the floor and ceiling are both undergoing [uniform acceleration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperbolic_motion_%28relativity%29) with the same center but different radii. The Euclidean analogue is circles with the same center but different radii having different circumferences. (Proper time in special relativity is the length of the worldline.) The Wikipedia article [Rindler coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rindler_coordinates) is also relevant, though not very readable.

Comment: @benrg Your reasoning implies both SR and the Equivalence principle, which make up a good deal of GR :-)

Comment: benrg, yes you are right, I don't need get into GR to understand this effect. I did get two things mixed up. I think I need to start by trying to understand where the equation is derived from. Thanks firtree, your comment helped.